# Proxify websocket requests in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, sails.js

We use React for the UI of our app and Sails.js back-end for managing users authentication and authorization. Also thanks to Sails we hide all API requests (those are made from React) to our external servers and we make sure that the requests are made only by authenticated users.

Here's how the requests flow look like: React <-> Sails <-> APIs.

Now one of our external servers supports websocket communication.

**How can React app communicate to the websocket server via Sails.js routes?**

Comment: By **hide** you mean reverse proxy right? Sails request to API and handles the request/response/authentication/authorization? Plus how are you communicating with **websockets** right now?

Comment: Yes, I mean **reverse proxy**.

Comment: Currently **websockets** are requested directly from the React UI with SocketJs and Stomp. In that scenariou the websocket's server IP is visible. We want to hide it with Sails.